# TF record corrupted after several successful training epochs

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I was training a neural network and had run over all the training data for several epochs successfully. 
However, the tfrecord corrputed error suddenly came out as follows:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py", line 77, in tf_record_iterator
  reader.GetNext(status)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
  self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
  pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: corrupted record at 106241330
```

I checked the data file again and it was indeed corrupted at that line. But the data was intact before I ran the training code and I simply just read the data by following code:

```
batch_data = []
record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=file, options=options)
for string_record in record_iterator:
  example = tf.train.Example()
  example.ParseFromString(string_record)
  data = generate_data_from_record(example) # record parsing code
  batch_data.append(data)
  if len(batch_data) == batch_size:
    yield batch_data
    batch_data = []
```

I am wondering why the data file was corrupted and how can I remain the integrity of the data file.

Comment: I don't think anybody can answer this question. The tensorflow code you posted would indeed only read the data. It could have been some other program that tried to write it or simply a disk error.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a clean copy of your `tfrecord` files. Whenever your working copy get corrupted, replace from the clean copy. The `dataLoss` error seems to be as a result of several reading of the same record, and its also dependent on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing this problem, the above answer by @nwoye-cid worked for me plus the link below to install everything properly.

Also, restart your kernel from scratch if nothing works then only go for other solutions.

[Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official#requirements)!